# awk, a field doesn't match but it should match

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, gawk

I have a file structured as record list, where field separator is \t.
I want to extract only records where the second field is a number from 1 to 9, but my awk script doesn't work.
The awk script is

```
cat file |awk -v FS="\t" '$2 ~ /[0-9]{1}/ {print $0;}'
```

or this

```
cat file |awk -v FS="\t" '$2 ~ /.{1}/ {print $0;}'  #because the second fields of my file have  all second fields as number
```

Why these sscript don't work? Isn't regex a good regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Even with the interval `{1}`, you are still going to match a field like `23` because the `2` matches a single number.  What you really want to use are anchors and forget about intervals:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^[0-9]$/{print}' FS="\t" file
```

---

The problem is the use of intervals `{1}`. `awk` less than version 4 doesn't support intervals.  `gawk` on the other hand will if you add the following flag: `--re-interval`

Try this:

```
awk --re-interval '$2 ~ /[0-9]{1}/{print}' FS="\t" file
```

Some other things to note:

1. Built in vars such as `FS` can be assigned at the end without the need for `-v`
2. You can use just `print` rather than `print $0` as that is its default behavior
3. Useless use of `cat`. `awk` can take a file as an argument, use that instead

Comment: We don't need `{print}` do we? Shouldn't `awk '$2 ~ /^[0-9]$/' FS="\t" file` suffice?

Comment: @SiegeX Thanks a lot. With --re-interval i have resolved. Thanks for advices.

Comment: The phrase 'awk less than version 4' doesn't really make much sense.  Awk is a language, not an implementation, and there is only one version.  There are many implementations, and most provide some extensions, but it's not at all clear which one you mean w.r.t.  version 4.

Comment: BusyBox awk supports {m,n} intervals. gawk v3 supports them with the --re-interval or --posix switches, but not the --traditional switch. gawk v4 assumes --re-interval by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the 2nd field is a single-digit number, you don't really need a regex:

```
awk '1 <= $2 && $2 <= 9 {print}'
```

Comment: Hi @glenn, shouldn't `awk '1 <= $2 && $2 <= 9'` be good enough? Sorry I have similar question posted above too since we are not printing any specific columns doing `{print}` will print the whole line by default. Sorry still learning :-)